# What does this integral notation mean?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, notation, bounds-of-integration

I'm talking about the integral part that is highlighted:

[image: How do I interpret this?]

Should I interpret the top one highlighted as the upper bound of integration and the bottom one as the lower bound? That's the only interpretation that made sense to me but I'm not sure. Thanks.

Comment: The inequalities describe a region in $\mathbb{R}^{i-1}$, the same as in the preceding line. It seems like $n$ in the integrand should be $i-1$, but perhaps $n$ (and $g$) are defined previously in a way that makes this make sense.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out !

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't order vectors in a geometrically sensible way, multiple integrals don't really have upper and lower bounds; they just have a set over which the integration occurs. Single integrals can be thought of in these terms too; if $a<b$, $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_{x\in[a,\,b]}f(x)dx$. (And you can integrate over other sets too, e.g. $\int_{[0,\,1]\cup[2,\,3]}f(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx+\int_2^3f(x)dx$.) In your integral, the highlighted conditions define the set of values for $x\in\Bbb R^n$ over which we integrate.

Comment: Because of the ellipsis and this alien notation (to me at least) I didn't even realize these were multiple integrals. So if I got you when we apply the two inequalities it's akin to calculating the volume of a "shaded area" (at least in R^2).

And when it comes to evaluating the integral, does this mean that I should keep integrating over this two-inequalities bounded area for EVERY integral?

Comment: @Metrician It's an $n$-tuple integral; we know this not only from the $dx_1\cdots dx_n$ (often denoted $d^nx$), but from the integration range being a subset of $\Bbb R^n$, but not a plane of lower dimension. Your shaded region intuition is exactly right for $g=1$; more generally, we can add another dimension to get a height of $g$ above the integration region, or take the original integral to be the mass if the region has density $g$. For evaluation, you do integrate over each coordinate, taking an integrand with one dimension removed, so it's recursive.

Comment: " taking an integrand with one dimension removed, so it's recursive"
Sorry but can you eleborate on this part, please?

And how should I go about practically using that region? Because if the region was defined as a clear set like the example you gave I'd have no issue with it. Normally if it's for example a region defined as " a < x < b " that's intuitive and you just apply those limits a & b. Plus the fact that there two inequalities usually in integrals over regions you have one inequality per integral of the type R={ (x,y): a < x < b,  c < y < d } instead of 2 here for many

Comment: The only thing that seems reasonable with my current (newbie) understanding is, since it's iterated over $x_k$, I integrate for x1 evaluated over the union of the area defined by both the inequalities, then the same with x2, until xn. Or is that wrong?

Comment: @Metrician Basically you write the integral as$$\int_{\min x_1}^{\max x_1}dx_1\int_{\min x_2(x_1)}^{\max x_2(x_1)}dx_2\int_{\min x_3(x_1,\,x_2)}^{\max x_3(x_1,\,x_2)}dx_3\cdots,$$where $\min x_2(x_1)$ is a function of $x_1$ etc. You evaluate the innermost integral first, i.e. you integrate $g dx_n$ over extrema of $x_n$ that depend on the other $x_k$. This gives a function of them, so now you can integrate out $x_{n-1}$ etc.

Comment: Thank you. I understood what you said. However, how do the min and max functions follow from that notation?

Comment: @Metrician They do, yes. You can do the same with $\sum_{(i_1,\,\cdots,\,i_n)\in S}g(i_1,\,\cdots,\,i_n)$.

Comment: Sorry if I formulated the question wrong but I meant  HOW do they follow from those equations? As you can tell I'm quite new to multivariable calculus so any dumbing down is more than welcomed

Comment: @Metrician A simpler example will help, especially if you draw a diagram. Let $S$ denote the triangle with vertices $(0,\,0),\,(0,\,1),\,(1,\,0)$. Its area is $\int_Sdxdy=\int_0^1dx\int_0^{1-x}dy=\tfrac12$.

Comment: I see. I guess the max/min are simply to designate the extremes of the defined bounds.This example is very intuitive to me since you're simply figuring out the line connecting the vertices and calculate the area of the formed triangle. The area of integration is quite intuitive here.  

But in the more abstract example above I'm not sure how to go about mechanically evaluating that integral and whether EACH individual integrand should be evaluated over both those inequalities?